# Facebook SDK for Windows Phone: AppAuthenticationHelper.IsFacebookLoginResponse changed to async

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-login

I want to implement a Facebook Login in my App with the [Facebook SDK for .NET/Windows Phone](http://facebooksdk.net/).

I followed the tutorials on these pages:

- [Sign into Windows Phone 8 apps with Facebook Login](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/11/14/sign-into-windows-phone-8-apps-with-facebook-login/)
- [Facebook Login for Windows Phone 8](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/sso/)

It looks like the API has changed because the method *AppAuthenticationHelper.IsFacebookLoginResponse(uri)* is async now and the *await* keyword is necessary. The problem is that I also need to change the return type from *Uri* to *Task* but thats not possible because it's an overridden method.

Sample code from pages above:

```
/// <summary>
/// Maps a deep link Uri to a navigation within this application
/// </summary>
/// <param name="uri">Deep link Uri to map</param>
/// <returns>Navigation Uri within this app</returns>
public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
{
    // if URI is a facebook login response, handle the deep link (once per invocation)
    if (AppAuthenticationHelper.IsFacebookLoginResponse(uri))
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

New code for async method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Maps a deep link Uri to a navigation within this application
/// </summary>
/// <param name="uri">Deep link Uri to map</param>
/// <returns>Navigation Uri within this app</returns>
public override Task<Uri> MapUri(Uri uri)
{
    // if URI is a facebook login response, handle the deep link (once per invocation)
    if (await AppAuthenticationHelper.IsFacebookLoginResponse(uri))
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

I know the APIs are still alpha and can change every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It is necessary to wrap the async operations into a seperate async method and call this method from the existing synchronous method.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Maps a deep link Uri to a navigation within this application
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">Deep link Uri to map</param>
    /// <returns>Navigation Uri within this app</returns>
    public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(async () => await MapUriAsync(uri));
        task.Wait();

        return task.Result;
    }

    private async Task<Uri> MapUriAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        // if URI is a facebook login response, handle the deep link (once per invocation)
        if (await AppAuthenticationHelper.IsFacebookLoginResponse(uri))
        {
            FacebookSession session = new FacebookSession();

            try
            {
                session.ParseQueryString(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString()));

                // Handle success case

                // do something with the custom state parameter
                if (session.State != "custom_state_string")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unexpected state: " + session.State);
                }
                else
                {
                    // save the token and continue (token is retrieved and used when the app
                    // is launched)
                    SessionStorage.Save(session);
                }
            }
            catch (Facebook.FacebookOAuthException exc)
            {
                if (!this.facebookLoginHandled)
                {
                    // Handle error case
                    MessageBox.Show("Not signed in: " + exc.Message);

                    this.facebookLoginHandled = true;
                }
            }

            return new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        }

        // by default, navigate to the requested uri
        return uri;
    }
```

For more information follow this link: http://sanjeev.dwivedi.net/?p=373